# Properties.Settings.Default.Save() won't save my changes

Tags: c#

I have a user setting which I want to increase by 1. E.g., if the value is currently 97, I want the new value to be 98. Next time, it should be increased to 99, etc.

I wrote the following code, but, after executing it, the value is unchanged. What did I do wrong?

```
int thumb = Properties.Settings.Default.Thumbnail;
thumb = thumb + 1;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You have to elaborate what you are asking, cause I have a hard time understanding what the question is.

Comment: My Question is Increase 1 Value and save setting in C#, I have taken a Thumbnail int user scope 97,  I want to add buttom click when click button 97, again click button 98, again click button 97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you create a local variable `thumb`, containing a local *copy* of the value currently stored in your settings:

```
int thumb = Properties.Settings.Default.Thumbnail;
```

Here, you increase your local copy:

```
thumb = thumb + 1;
```

Here, you save the values as they were before (since you only incremented the local copy):

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

---

Thus, to fix your issue, you have to explicitly set the new value in your settings:

```
int thumb = Properties.Settings.Default.Thumbnail;
thumb = thumb + 1;

// add this:
Properties.Settings.Default.Thumbnail = thumb;

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: How to Load Value in FormLoad